# Ionic Notification has no sound

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

Look like there were some changes in Ionic Push Notification in the last few weeks.

**OLD WAY**

```
$ionicPush.register({
      canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
      canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
      canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
      canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        // Handle new push notifications here
        alert(notification);
        return true;
      }
    });
```

[image]

**NEW WAY**

```
$ionicPush.init({
  "debug": true,
  "onNotification": function(notification) {
    var payload = notification.payload;
    console.log(notification, payload);
  },
  "onRegister": function(data) {
    console.log(data.token);
});

$ionicPush.register();
```

[image]

You can see that the different code in latest release preventing iOS from having sound and other features. I tried to add back `canPlaySound: true` in `$ionicPush.init` but it didn't work.

How do I get back the list of all notification features for ios?

**UPDATE**

Correct answer

```
$ionicPush.init({
  "debug": true,
  "onNotification": function(notification) {
    var payload = notification.payload;
    console.log(notification, payload);
  },
  "onRegister": function(data) {
    console.log(data.token);
  },
  "pluginConfig": {
    "ios": {
      "badge": true,
      "sound": true
     },
     "android": {
       "iconColor": "#343434"
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are plugin options which I've added to our docs:

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-usage#section-plugin-options

Comment: That new example is full of typos (bracket and comma). Anyways, I updated it